# Deploying MVC/EF site to test server problems

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework, reflection, deployment

I have a MVC3/EF4 site that runs fine on my dev machine Win7, but when deployed to a test server Win2003 throws the error:

> "Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information.
>
> Exception Details: System.Reflection.ReflectionTypeLoadException:
>   Unable to load one or more of the requested types. Retrieve the
>   LoaderExceptions property for more information."

My question is twofold. Anything obvious I should check first? Secondly how do I look through the LoaderExceptions?

Thanks.

Comment: Obvious: is MVC3 installed on test server? Also - what .NET Framework version is installed and what .NET version specified in application pool settings for your site?

Comment: For the second part of your question - there is an useful utility called Fusion Log Viewer (fuslogvw.exe) in Visual Studio/.NET SDK which logs all assembly bindings that happen on your system. More info [in MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e74a18c4.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the Portable Type Library I was using. There is a known bug whereby the System. XML version that is trying to be called is the 2.0 version not the 4.0 version (http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/b0e0b5e9-e138-410b-ad10-00cb3caf4981/). To resolve this ensure VS2010 SP1 is installed and remove the binding manually. In my case I have another computer that it worked on so I used this as the master and everything worked fine.

Hope this help someone else.